# Android final variable error

Tags: java, android, string, final

When i write this code i see this error.

i see "The final local variable peyvaDawi cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type" in marked line.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ferheng=new Veritabani(this);
    final ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnBigere);
    final EditText edtPeyv=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPeyv);
    final RadioButton rbKT=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbKT);
    final RadioButton rbTK=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbTK);

    final String peyvaDawi="emre";
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            final boolean KT=rbKT.isChecked();
            final boolean TK=rbTK.isChecked();

            sonuc="";
            String strPeyv=edtPeyv.getText().toString();
            Boolean tenePeyv=false;
            if(strPeyv==peyvaDawi)
                tenePeyv=true;
            else
                tenePeyv=false;
            if(KT)
                Arama(strPeyv,"kurdi",tenePeyv);
            if(TK)
                Arama(strPeyv,"tirki",tenePeyv);
                            peyvaDawi=strPeyv;//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< i see error in this line.

        }
    });
}
```

i see error in line peyvaDawi=strPeyv;

Comment: never compare strings with ==.

Answer (score 3):

peyvaDawi is declared as final, and so you can't re-assign it once it has been assigned a value. Just don't do this. Why would you want to change the value of a local String variable whose scope is limited to this method anyway?

Also don't compare Strings using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that == checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if ("bar".equals(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if ("bar".equalsIgnoreCase(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

Also you should enclose ***all*** blocks in curly braces including all if, else blocks, even if they're only one line long so as not to mislead yourself into thinking a line of code is in the block due to misplaced indentations when in fact it isn't.